# Lost access rights and permissions to secondary storage drive 'Program Files'. How do I regain control?

Tags: windows-7, permissions, file-permissions, administrator, uac

My problem is - I am unable to delete/uninstall/overwrite all folders and files inside of 'Program Files' in my storage E: drive, my operating system is installed in C: drive.

I've read posts of similar problems from here and other forums and I have tried everything and nothing seems to have had any effect.

- I am an administrator
- I have UAC disabled
- I have total control over all files and folders in C: and every other folder in E: including Program Files (x86) so its only in **E:\Program Files** where I don't have control
- I can create folders inside of Program files but when i try to delete them I get an error message : `you require permission from administrators to make changes to this folder`. Some folders/files say instead that I require permission from SYSTEM.
- When I try and cut a New Folder I just created in program files it says it can't be completed because its open in another program.
- I have installed **'Take Control'** right click function and tried that function on various files and folders within program files including program files itself. This only gives error message: `Access is denied`.
- In program files properties all accounts have full control except Users which only have *read + execute*, list folder contents and read permissions
- I have tried program files *right click, properties, security, advanced* and anything I try and change in these options gives the error message: U`nable to save permission changes on Program Files. Access is denied`
- I am unable to tick the boxes to **'include inheritable permissions....'** and **replace all child object permissions...**
- I am unable to edit anything in program files *properties, security, edit,* when I try change the owner to someone else it says an error occurred while applying security information : `unable to set`
- Also I'm not sure if its related but I am unable to update to the latest version of itunes or anti malware bytes which are installed in **E:\Program Files**.
- I have also tried running **cmd.exe** as admin and the whole `takeown /f /r /a` thing just says access is denied unless I am typing it in wrong, the instructions I found on this website in another post were kind of confusing. I structured it as: `C:\takeown /f "E:\Program Files" /r`
- I also tried `C:\takeown /f "E:\Program Files"` and `C:\takeown /r "E:\Program Files"`

I feel like perhaps I didn't follow one of the steps properly even though I have been relentlessly trying to solve this and have explored seemingly all possible solutions. I am knowledgeable with computers but not when it comes to registry editing and advanced command prompt rules etc.

Please help me! Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/i-want-full-access-to-all-my-files-and-folders-in/1567bf63-b1f5-40a5-be3f-150dce4c5aed

Answer (score 1):

Source [Take Ownership of a File, Folder, Drive, or Registry Key in Windows 8](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/2808-take-ownership-file-folder-drive-registry-key-windows-8-a.html):

**Take Ownership of an Object using TAKEOWN Command**

This command will take ownership of the folder or drive, and all files and subfolders in the folder or drive.

Open an [elevated command prompt](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/2754-elevated-command-prompt-open-windows-8-a.html).

To grant ownership to administrators group:

```
takeown /F "full path of folder or drive" /A /R /D Y
```

Example:

```
takeown /F "E:" /A /R /D Y
```

**To Take Ownership of Only a Folder or Drive using ICALCS Command**

Open an [elevated command prompt](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/2754-elevated-command-prompt-open-windows-8-a.html).

To set administrators group as owner:

```
icacls "full path of folder or drive" /setowner "Administrators" /C
```

Example:

```
icacls "E:\Folder" /setowner "Administrators" /C
```

**To Take Ownership of a Folder or Drive and All Contents using ICALCS Command**

Open an [elevated command prompt](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/2754-elevated-command-prompt-open-windows-8-a.html).

To set administrators group as owner:

```
icacls "full path of folder or drive" /setowner "Administrators" /T /C
```

Example:

```
icacls "E:\Folder" /setowner "Administrators" /T /C
```

Comment: Thankyou so much for the quick response! I just went through all the steps but unfortunately every single one gave the same response: Access is denied. This is such a joke....

Answer (score 0):

Taking ownership of system files or folders in Windows is not a simple task. Whether you use the GUI or the command line, it takes far too many steps.

But on internet I got a registery file which will change the permission and allow anything to perform on windows file.

see the steps posted in below link for more information [Click here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-take-ownership-to-explorer-right-click-menu-in-vista/)
Or on [This link](http://www.winmatrix.com/forums/index.php?/topic/13157-easy-way-to-take-ownership-of-system-files-in-windows-7-8-and-vista/)

Comment: I completely agree, i have literally tried everything now and nothing has worked, i have already tried the take ownership right click option and i tried the program in your link but both didnt work. Thankyou so much for your help anyways :) :)

Answer (score 0):

This is my "chown.bat" (unix folks will laugh at me using that name). I've cobbled it together from various solutions... Each time one doesn't work, I add more stuff. The SetACL stuff I only discovered in 2014 or 2015. This has never failed me:

```
    for /r %fn in (*.*)  SetACL -on "%fn" -ot file -actn clear -clr dacl,sacl
    takeown /F * /R /D  Y
    icacls   *.* /T /C /grant %_winuser%:(D,WDAC)
    icacls    .  /T /C /grant administrators:F System:F everyone:F
```

SetACL is a 3rd party utility that needs to be in your path.